# ag-grid: Refresh current view with 'serverSide' rowModel

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid

Very simple question, with a seemingly impossible to find answer:

When using [`gridOptions:{ rowModel: 'serverside'}`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model/) data is loaded through the `getRows` callback.

But how can we simply "refresh" the grid, so that it executes the last getRows call again and updates the data in place?

Right now it seems absolutely impossible to do this without calling [`gridApi.purgeServerSideCache()`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model/#server-side-model-api), however this results in the collapse of all opened row groups which I'd like to avoid for obvious UX reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link to ag-grid documentation should be helpful: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model-grouping/#preserving-group-state

Essentially, the docs state that using gridApi.purgeServerSideCache() is the preferred way to force a reload, but they go on to say the following which should solve the UX concerns you have:

> **Preserving Group State**
>
> It may be necessary to expand groups to a
>   desired initial state or to restore the grid to a previous state after
>   purging / reloading data.
>
> This can be achieved by expanding row nodes as blocks are loaded in
>   the Server-side Datasource. The following snippet outlines a possible
>   approach:

```
 function getRows(params) {
>     // 1) get data from server
>     var response = getServerResponse(params.request);
> 
>     // 2) call the success callback
>     params.successCallback(response.rowsThisBlock, response.lastRow);
> 
>     // 3) to preserve group state we expand any previously expanded groups for this block
>     rowsInThisBlock.forEach(row => {
>         if (expandedGroupIds.indexOf(row.id) > -1) {
>             gridOptions.api.getRowNode(row.id).setExpanded(true);
>         }
>     }); 
>  }
```

> Notice that in step 3, newly loaded row nodes for the current block are expanded if they are defined in expandedGroupIds,
>   which is an array of group keys maintained by the application. This
>   will have a cascading effect as expanding a group will cause new
>   block(s) to load.
>
> In order to easily look up group row nodes, implementing the following
>   callback is recommended: gridOptions.getRowNodeId().

Comment: This definitely works, but get's tedious when dealing with multiple, customized grids because one needs to save the entire grid state and restore it after each refresh.
For anyone with simple grids: Try this answer.
I personally decided to patch ag-grid directly so we can refresh single rows and keep everything else in tact. Sadly I'm not allowed to share the code.
I'll accept this as answer though for the time being.

Comment: @Xceno I agree that you can't share the code but this is a good contribution for the rest of the developers in the world, doing the same thing. Do you think you can at least guide the developers with your solution ideas?